# \Longrightarrow symbol in kpfonts doesn't look okay when used with beamer class

Tags: beamer, symbols, kpfonts

The following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
%
\begin{document}
\Huge%
$A\Longrightarrow B$
\end{document}
```

points out that `\Longrightarrow` symbol in `kpfonts` looks:

- okay when used with (e.g.) `article` class:

[image]

- **not** okay when used  with `beamer` class:

[image]

Do you see what's going on?

Comment: Yes, that you forgot `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=professionalfonts+is%3Aanswer

Comment: @egreg Huh?! Where is this `professionalfonts` documented?

Comment: @egreg Very strange: I couldn't find anything related to `professionalfonts` in `beamer`'s documentation because there is no such string in it. But `professionalfont` (without trailing `s`) is documented, as class option (okay) but also as font theme: `\usefonttheme{professionalfont}` which is wrong: only `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` is known. Hence an inconsistency in `beamer` here: the font theme should be named as the equivalent class option.

Comment: I seem to recall something like that. Anyway, this is the correct option, as far as I know.

Comment: @egreg Issue [already reported](https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issues/293/typo-in-user-guide-professionalfont) and resolved (but fix still not published).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macro `\Longrightarrow` uses `\Relbar` for making a longer arrow; it is just the “standard equals sign” as defined by `amsmath`.

However, this uses `\textfont0` that is bound to the standard font family, unless you use the `professionalfonts` font theme. Compare the outpu with the comment and without it

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

$A\Longrightarrow B$

\scriptsize
\texttt{\meaning\Longrightarrow}

\texttt{\meaning\Relbar}

\texttt{\expandafter\meaning\csname std@equal\endcsname}

\texttt{\fontname\textfont0}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output without the font theme

[image]

### Output with the font theme

[image]